# WebStorm type checking React props using type definition

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webstorm, tsd

I'm using WebStorm 2018.3.4 and am trying to figure out how to do type checking on a React component's props. Specifically, if a prop is marked as a `string` but I give it a `number` I want WebStorm to show an error. I've created a type definition file (as described [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/static-type-checking.html#type-definitions)). Here's what the file looks like:

**MyComponent.d.ts**

```js
import * as React from 'react';

export interface MyComponentProps {
  /** this is the component's title */
  title: string;

  /** this is a short description of the component */
  description?: string;
}

declare class MyComponent extends React.Component<MyComponentProps, {}> {
  render(): JSX.Element;
}

export default MyComponent;
```

**App.jsx**

```
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <MyComponent title={7} />
    );
  }
}
```

I was hoping WebStorm would underline `title={7}` telling me that `7` is the wrong type. If I `Ctrl+Q` on the prop it definitely tells me the type is `string` and it gives me the documentation from the `.d.ts` file. Is there a setting I need to enable? Or does WebStorm not support this? Or is my problem that my app is using JSX rather than TypeScript? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Webstorm doesn't provide props types checking (i.e. it doesn't report type mismatching). If you miss this feature, please file a feature request to youtrack, https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WEB

Comment: Thanks @lena! That's what I thought and just wanted to confirm.

Answer (score -1):

You can install [prop-types](https://www.npmjs.com/package/prop-types)

Then you can write your component like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

class App extends Component {
    static propTypes = {
        userId: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
        someObject: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
        someFunction: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    };

    render() {
       ....
    }
}
```

Comment: This definitely works for required props, but WebStorm will not warn if the types of the given props are different than what is defined.